# SVN Issues "redirect cycle detected" on Shared Hosting

Tags: svn

I can't understand what am I doing wrong. I want to have a Subversion Repository in my Shared Hosting and I want to be able to checkout all files to my local PC using e.g. TortoiseSVN

So what I'm doing:

1) I created repository using my SSH in the /home/myaccount/public_html/svn/ folder

```
svnadmin create public_html/svn
```

2) it creates the repository with all folders:

- /public_html/svn/conf
- /public_html/svn/db
- /public_html/svn/hooks
- /public_html/svn/locks

3) Then I edited conf/svnserve.conf and conf/passwd

conf/svnserve.conf

```
anon-access = none  
auth-access = write  
password-db = passwd
```

conf/passwd

```
john = mypassword
```

**Then Start Problems**

4) Trying to create /myproject/ folder in /svn/ folder

```
cd /home/myaccount/public_html/svn/
svn mkdir myproject
```

It returns "svn: 'public_html/svn' is not a working copy"
**Why I get this error?**

5) Ok, I'm trying to browse my svn directory using TortoiseSVN Browser, I'm inserting this URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn/ 
The xxx... is my Dedicated IP Address of my Shared Hosting

Ok I'm waiting and expecting to see the /svn/ folder but it returns this error:

> Redirect Cycle Dedicated for http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn/

And that's it, I have two issues now, and I can't understand the reason, please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting svn started is tricky.  This is something to try at this point (assumes public_html directory is under ~ or $HOME):

```
cd $HOME
mkdir init_project1
cd init_project1
echo "Directory under svn revision control." > readme.txt
cd $HOME
svn import init_project1 file://$HOME/public_html/svn/project1 -m "Initial import"
cd $HOME
rm -rf init_project1
svn co file://$HOME/public_html/svn/project1
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot cforbish!
All these steps worked, my svn repository is created successfully. Now I'm trying to checkout it to my local PC folder using TortoiseSVN. 
I'm using this urls: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/svn/project1 But it returns this error "PROPFIND request on '/svn/project1' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed" Is this a hosting issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

You made a lot of mistakes and (probably wrong) assumptions

1. Are you absolutely sure, that svnserve **is** on your hosting?
2. Even if it installed, is it **running**?
3. Even if it running, **which configuration** it used?
4. If it running and serve all repositories on host, why you tried to checkout http:// type repository?
5. Why you used this strange and wrong URL, which will be wrong even after changing http:// to svn://
6. Why hosting-specific questions and problems you tried to solve here, and not with hosting's support staff? We aren't sensitives to answer on questions 1-3

**Thinking:**

In the assumptions

- svnserve is running as daemon
- svnserve port is not redefined
- svnserve is not rooted

using [svnserve, a Custom Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) from SVN Book as starting point, namely this para

> Once we successfully start svnserve as explained previously, it makes
>   every repository on your system available to the network. A client
>   needs to specify an *absolute* path in the repository URL. For example,
>   if a repository is located at `/var/svn/project1`, a client would reach
>   it via `svn://host.example.com/var/svn/project1`

I'll suggest these actions

- Create new repository **outside web-space** (for svn:// reposiritories http-browsing of repo doesn't give anything useful and readable, don't mix svn:// and http:// repo)
- Identify full path to te repo-dir (`pwd`)
- Construct real URL of your repo, it will be smth. like `svn://SERVERNAME/home/myaccount/svn/`
- Test repo in TSVN's repo-browser from external world or (better) from CLI svn-client: (in case of error you'll get more detailed description of problem) `svn ls svn://SERVERNAME/home/myaccount/svn/`

Comment: maybe you can try being a bit more polite next time and assume that when the OP says "2) it creates the repository with all folders:" he probably has svn installed. Afaik points 1-3 are not wrongly assumed by the OP just by fully reading his question. -- last comment: your answer is pretty useless to this OP, although it might be usefull to other people.